# Is it normal for my avocado plant’s leaves to be yellowish green?

Tags: plant-health, avocado

My avocado plant is starting to get slightly yellow leaves. I’m worried about it and just want to know if this is normal. I have a couple of pictures. We grew this one from a pit. It started to grow quite a few months ago, though I’m not sure when. We recently planted it and I’ve never noticed this one looking like this. Is there anything wrong with it? What can I do (if this isn’t normal) to fix it? I’ll add photos if needed. :-)

Comment: A picture would really help!

Comment: How "recently planted"? Check the top of branches. It may be just stress to be planted in a new place (or maybe too much water or heavy soil?, or too acid? [if you overdid with fertilizers])